# Using jQuery and jQueryUI Sortable with Laravel Elixir

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3

I use jQuery and jQuery UI Sortable for sorting some items in an Laravel 5.3 application, but I can't figure out how to use jQuery and jQuery UI correctly in the `app.js` file.

I've tried both `require('jquery')` (which works great), and also `require('jquery-ui')` which also works without any error messages.

A recipe I found stated that I could use the following code for using jQuery and jQueryUI together in the JS file:

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery-ui'], function($, ui) {
    // $.ui should be defined, but do
    // $.ui = ui if its not

    $.ui = ui;

    $.ui('#page-list').sortable();
});
```

But this returns the following error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined (widget.js?e6d7:93)`

So that means that jQuery and jQuery UI works, but what can be the issue? Maybe the jQuery version?

Comment: did you found any solution to this?